# Filter array items by a certain string

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I am new to C# and I've been trying to make a simple method that is supposed to take a string array and a prefix, then filter the array items by the prefix.

Basically, if I pass an array like `string[] data = "A horse, or a HORSE!!!".Split(' ');` to it it should return `{"horse,","HORSE!!!"}` if the prefix = "horse". Naturally, if an empty string prefix is passed, it should return every item. I think I got close to getting it right myself, but now I hit the wall.

I also wanted it to return the ArgumentIsNull exception for when prefix = null. But weirdly it just doesn't want to trigger! I tested and the exception is thrown when there is no foreach loop, but isn't with foreach. Why does it behave like that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Enumerable
{
    public class EnumerableManipulation
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetPrefixItems(IEnumerable<string> data, string prefix)
        {
            if (prefix == null) 
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(); 
            } 
            ///Why does this exception never trigger when I pass a null prefix? But it works if there is no foreach.

            foreach (string item in data)
            {
                ///I thought this would do the trick and now I can't figure out why it doesn't work
                if (data.All(prefix.Contains))
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it?  I'm trying:

```
var x = new EnumerableManipulation();
var ret = x.GetPrefixItems(new[] { "One", "Two"}, null);
```

And I get the exception.

Comment: If you put a break point in like `prefix == null`, what is the value for prefix?, if the exception was no throw it is because the if condition is false, you could also change the `string prefix` parameter in the method to `string? prefix`

Comment: What version of C# are you using? If you're using nullable reference types there is no way  `prefix == null` could ever be true and you should remove that bit of code.

Comment: I think it's also possible you're not materializing the enumeration yet.  Simply calling the method won't throw the exception right away, you'll need to enumerate through the results.

Answer (score 1):

It is an enumeration. All of your code including the stuff happening before the yield, will only be executed, if you actually enumerate through the result of your function. By calling .ToList() or by a foreach loop.

If you do this:

```
var result = GetPrefixItems(..., null).ToList()
```

It should give you an exception.

Comment: This is almost for sure what's going on..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to yield the output then you can use `Linq` to filter your array like following:

```
IEnumerable<string> data = "A horse, or a HORSE!!!".Split(' ');
IEnumerable<string> result = data.Where(x => x.Contains("horse"));
```